# how to read EC pem file to return private key integer?

Tags: python, cryptography

I have an EC private key like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgSV6yVAIJil6nb3fN
zbRkMpIzDGjxooZRfZVYaoiDnLmhRANCAASgQDzFeJoU1etfMcPu5PeDXqnV4K4d
7lTj+RQaR/eE2DwCzZMq0y/Fvl8/S5JvWnscCjSwVu50nY2G3yrR/YgI
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

how can i read this file to return the private key integer with python?

I know I have to convert pem to der. Then use asn1 to decode der but i still don't know how to find the position of the private key integer.

<s>using `asn1` library gives me this:</s>

```
b'\x02\x01\x000\x13\x06\x07*\x86H\xce=\x02\x01\x06\x08*\x86H\xce=\x03\x01\x07\x04m0k\x02\x01\x01\x04 I^\xb2T\x02\t\x8a^\xa7ow\xcd\xcd\xb4d2\x923\x0ch\xf1\xa2\x86Q}\x95Xj\x88\x83\x9c\xb9\xa1D\x03B\x00\x04\xa0@<\xc5x\x9a\x14\xd5\xeb_1\xc3\xee\xe4\xf7\x83^\xa9\xd5\xe0\xae\x1d\xeeT\xe3\xf9\x14\x1aG\xf7\x84\xd8<\x02\xcd\x93*\xd3/\xc5\xbe_?K\x92oZ{\x1c\n4\xb0V\xeet\x9d\x8d\x86\xdf*\xd1\xfd\x88\x08'
```

<s>but then how can i find the location of private key integer?</s>

I'm using `pyasn1` library now.

```
f = open(filename, "rb")
content = f.read()

# convert pem to der
content = content.replace(b"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", b"")
content = content.replace(b"-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", b"")
content = codecs.decode(content, 'base64')

# decode der with asn1 library
decoder = decoder.decode(content)
```

Output:

```
(<Sequence value object, tagSet=<TagSet object, tags 0:32:16>, subtypeSpec=<ConstraintsIntersection object>, componentType=<NamedTypes object, types >, sizeSpec=<ConstraintsIntersection object>, payload [<Integer value object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 0:0:2>, payload [0]>, <SequenceOf value object, tagSet=<TagSet object, tags 0:32:16>, subtypeSpec=<ConstraintsIntersection object>, componentType=None, sizeSpec=<ConstraintsIntersection object>, payload [<ObjectIdentifier value object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 0:0:6>, payload [1.2.840.10045.2.1]>, <ObjectIdentifier value object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 0:0:6>, payload [1.2.840.10045.3.1.7]>]>, <OctetString value object, tagSet <TagSet object, tags 0:0:4>, encoding iso-8859-1, payload [0x306b0201010420...8d86df2ad1fd8808]>]>, b'')
```

still trying to read the private key integer.

(this is a migration question from https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/102198/how-to-read-ec-pem-file-to-return-private-key-integer)

Comment: Libraries like PyCryptodome or Cryptography support the import of PEM keys (like the posted one) as well as the reading of the key parameters. Have a look at the documentations.

Comment: i can't use those libraries. must convert to der then read the private key integer @Topaco

Comment: PEM->DER: Remove header, footer, line breaks and Base64 decode the rest. The easiest way to get the position of the raw private key is to use an ASN.1 parser, e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js: It's the 0x495e... octet string.

Comment: By the way, what you posted is almost the entire DER encoded key (only the first three bytes 0x308187 are missing). Please post your Python code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following screenshot shows the key in an ASN.1 parser:

[image]

The first sequence contains three elements, the third is an octet string containing the raw keys. pyasn1 numbers the elements of a sequence by starting with field-0, so the octet string is field-2.

The octet string also contains a sequence with three elements, where the second (field-1) is an octet string containing the private key, and the third (field-2) is a bit string containing the uncompressed public key.

The raw keys can be determined e.g. as follows:

```py
from pyasn1.codec.der import decoder 
import codecs

content = b'''-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgSV6yVAIJil6nb3fN
zbRkMpIzDGjxooZRfZVYaoiDnLmhRANCAASgQDzFeJoU1etfMcPu5PeDXqnV4K4d
7lTj+RQaR/eE2DwCzZMq0y/Fvl8/S5JvWnscCjSwVu50nY2G3yrR/YgI
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'''

# convert pem to der
content = content.replace(b"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", b"")
content = content.replace(b"-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", b"")
content = codecs.decode(content, 'base64')

# decode der with asn1 library
# - get the octet string (field-2) containing the raw key
asn1Object, _ = decoder.decode(content)
rawKeys = asn1Object.getComponentByName('field-2').asOctets()
# - get the octet string (field-1) containing the raw private key 
#   and the bit string (field-2) containing the uncompressed public key
asn1Object, _ = decoder.decode(rawKeys)
privateKey = asn1Object.getComponentByName('field-1').asOctets()
print(f'Private key (hex):             {privateKey.hex()}')
print(f'Private key (int):             {int.from_bytes(privateKey, byteorder="big")}')
uncompressedPublicKey = asn1Object.getComponentByName('field-2').asOctets()
print(f'Uncompressed public key (hex): {uncompressedPublicKey.hex()}')
```

with the output:

```
Private key (hex):             495eb25402098a5ea76f77cdcdb4643292330c68f1a286517d95586a88839cb9
Private key (int):             33186152346367412559435662348499442917353988360058129868465754729056265542841
Uncompressed public key (hex): 04a0403cc5789a14d5eb5f31c3eee4f7835ea9d5e0ae1dee54e3f9141a47f784d83c02cd932ad32fc5be5f3f4b926f5a7b1c0a34b056ee749d8d86df2ad1fd8808
```

---

It is also possible to specify a related Python class (based on the [pyasn1](https://github.com/etingof/pyasn1#asn1-library-for-python) data model) for the mapping with an ASN.1 structure, s. [pyasn1 type objects](https://github.com/inexio/pyasn1/blob/master/pyasn1/codec/der/decoder.py#L62).
In the [pyasn1 modules](https://github.com/etingof/pyasn1-modules#asn1-modules-for-python) package there is a comprehensive collection of such classes for various ASN.1 structures (which is extensible using the [asn1ate](https://github.com/kimgr/asn1ate) tool).
For example, for decoding an ASN.1 encoded private EC key in PKCS#8 format, the classes [`rfc5208.PrivateKeyInfo`](https://github.com/etingof/pyasn1-modules/blob/master/pyasn1_modules/rfc5208.py) and [`rfc5915.ECPrivateKey`](https://github.com/etingof/pyasn1-modules/blob/master/pyasn1_modules/rfc5915.py) are to be used.
With this, the unspecific namings in the above example are replaced by the corresponding definitions from these classes:

```py
from pyasn1.codec.der import decoder 
from pyasn1_modules import rfc5208
from pyasn1_modules import rfc5915
...
asn1Object, _ = decoder.decode(content, asn1Spec=rfc5208.PrivateKeyInfo())
rawKeys = asn1Object.getComponentByName('privateKey').asOctets()
asn1Object, _ = decoder.decode(rawKeys, asn1Spec=rfc5915.ECPrivateKey())
privateKey = asn1Object.getComponentByName('privateKey').asOctets()
uncompressedPublicKey = asn1Object.getComponentByName('publicKey').asOctets()
```